# Installing touchfreeze on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I have a dell E5570, running 14.04, and am trying to deal with the cursed touchpad problem.    Some of the solutions suggested on the web are 
   a) use syndaemon, but this is unsatisfactory because even with a very short transition time --- I'm using

```
syndaemon -i 0.2 -d -R
```

there are still long pauses sometimes before my typing shows up
  b) toggle the touchpad on and off, which is obviously extremely unsatisfactory.

So I've tried to install touchfreeze from [this site](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/TouchFreeze-28533.shtml#download).
Touchfreeze worked really well on my old laptop running 12.04, but this version throws an error when I attempt to `make` it.   Here's the output:

```
root@E5570:local/src/touchfreeze-0.2.5#make
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o touchfreeze main.o TouchFreezeApp.o TouchFreezeUI.o SynDaemon.o moc_TouchFreezeApp.o moc_TouchFreezeUI.o moc_SynDaemon.o qrc_stuff.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: SynDaemon.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XQueryKeymap'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [touchfreeze] Error 1
```

Any suggestions about how to fix this would be most appreciated.  or another alternative way to fix the jumpy touchpad problem.

Thanks!

http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/TouchFreeze-28533.shtml#download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touchfreeze is a reasonably old application that has not seen a lot of recent development. A better choice might be gpointing-device-settings:

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

which will give you some of the functionality you are after in Trusty. This functionality is part of the basic 'Mouse and Touchpad' settings in Wily Werewolf 15.10 but not for Trusty unfortunately...

Comment: Thanks @andrew.46, have installed it, and will see what happens.   I did get an error on install, don't know if it's important.   `An X error occurred. The error was BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter).`